# Convergence of random variables in LP preserved under conditioning on sub sigma field

Tags: pr.probability

Is anyone aware of a result which states that convergence of random variables in $\mathbb L^p$ are preserved under conditioning on sub-sigma fields?

I'm new to probability/measure theory, and trying to get a handle on the idea of combining $\mathbb L^p$ spaces with conditioning. I was trying to tackle this with martingales, but I fear that I may be way off the reservation. Any guidance would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an immediate consequence of the [conditional Jensen inequality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality#Proof_3_.28general_inequality_in_a_probabilistic_setting.29).

Comment: Sorry, I'm being dense, but can you please be a little more explicit about the setup? I'm unclear where the convexity enters the picture.

Comment: @Matt: $\varphi(x) := |x|^p$ is a convex function.  Apply the inequality, then take unconditional expectation of both sides.  Finally replace $X$ by $X_n - X$.